# How to Use Input() with Row String

Tags: python-3.x

I have a small project to batch rename files. I'm using the `Python OS` library and the way to read the directory paths is the `raw string` typed directly into the variable. However, I want to add an interactive window to my program with `PySimpleGUI` and receive the directory path by user input, but I am not able to do this because the `raw string` only accepts direct input of data. I can't make it read the content of a variable (which would be exactly the variable in which the user typed the path of the directory that will be read). I haven't applied PySimpleGUI yet because I haven't solved this problem yet. The code is right below:

```
import space
import os
import time
import thankyoumessage

class Renevolution:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def start(self,folder,new):
        counter_folders = 0        
        start_process = time.time()
        for file_name in os.listdir(folder_path):
            old_name = folder + file_name
            current_name = new + old_name
            os.rename(old_name,current_name)


        for counter in range(counter_folders): 
            print(os.listdir(folder_path))
        
        
        end_process = time.time()
        space.space()
        enumerate_files = 1
        for file in range(counter_folders):
            print(f'{enumerate_files} File - {folder_path[file]}')
            enumerate_files += 1
        return f'Process finished in {(end_process - start_process):.2f} seconds. \033[1;33m\n{space.space()}\nEnd of Program!'

space.space()
RT = Renevolution()
folder_path = input('Enter the path of folder > ')
new_name = input('What do you wish to insert which name in the folder(s)? >')
print(RT.start(folder_path,new_name))
```

I tried to use other features of the OS library, but without much return for the type of program I'm wanting to make. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What's a "row string"?  Is that a PySimpleGUI term or a path term?  I've not heard it before.  If you want to pre-fill a PySimpleGUI `Input` element with a default value you can do that, but I have a feeling that's not what you mean.

Comment: @MikefromPSG from PSG. `Raw String` is a parameter used for python to read a string of characters in a "raw" way, that is, disregarding any command inside it (like \n for example). Look:

```import os

path = r'C:\test\\'
print(os.listdir(path))```

The raw_string is used to pass the `OS` library the path where the files I want to batch rename are. My question really has nothing to do with ```PySimpleGUI```, but with the .rename() functionality of the `OS` library.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!  Just wanted to be sure it wasn't a PySimpleGUI issue.  Hopefully someone will come through.... have you asked an AI bot (insert -SIGH- here)?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean in your question, but if it is to do with python's raw string literals i.e. `r'C:\test\\'`, I assume you don't actually know what they are. Raw string literals are denoted with the `r'...'`, and are used for hard coding values like file paths, but when the program is run, they are not treated specially and are just normal strings. All they do is prevent the string from being created incorrectly, but have no bearing at runtime. I don't know if this will help or if I've misunderstood the question, but lmk if you need me to clarify or help with your code.

Comment: If nothing wrong, you can use `input` or `Input` element to read the path string directly, don't care about the raw string issue.